# How to divide day hours from night hours between 2 time fields

Tags: if-statement, time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to separate night hours and day hours between 2 times, if the time is between 6:00 am to 6:59 pm it should be day time and if the time is between 7:00 pm and 5:59 am it should be night time. Then I need to multiply night time by 1.25 and add it to day time if any.

I have tried with this formula but it seems to complex and sometimes it does not work

`H4=if(G4 = 0,0,IF(AND(E4 > = TIME(19 , 0 , 0),F4 < = TIME( 6 , 0 , 0)), 0 ,IF(and(E4 < TIME(19 , 0 , 0),F4 < = TIME( 6 , 0 , 0)),F4-TIME(6, , ),IF(and(AND(E4 > = TIME(19, 0 , 0),F4>TIME(6, 0  ,0)),F4 < = TIME(19,0  , 0)),F4 - TIME(6 , 0 , 0 ),IF(and(and(E4 < TIME(19, 0 , 0 ),F4 > = TIME(6 , 0 , 0)),E4<TIME(6 , , )),F4 - TIME(6 , ,),IF(and(E4 < TIME(19 , , ),F4 < TIME(19 , , )), F4 - E4,IF(AND(E4 > = TIME(19 , 0 , 0 ),F4 < = TIME(23 ,59 ,0 )), 0 ,IF(E4 < TIME( 19 , 0 , 0 ),TIME( 19 , 0 , 0 ) - E4 , 0 ))))))))`

I have the following structure:

```
G4=(F4-E4+(F4 < E4))
E4 is my start time ex: 11:01:00 PM
F4 is my end time ex 1:35:00 AM
```

Is there an easier way to get the division between times as to get the time I have to then do I4=G4-H4

[image: This is how the sheet looks like]

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in **G4:I** range

paste this into **G4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F4:F<>"", TEXT(F4:F-E4:E+(F4:F<E4:E), "[h]:mm:ss"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste this into **H4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F4:F>E4:E, TEXT((F4:F-E4:E)+
 IF(E4:E-0.25>0,, E4:E-0.25)+
 IF(0.7916666667-F4:F>0,, 0.7916666667-F4:F), 
 "[h]:mm:ss"),""))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste this into **I4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((G4:G<>"")*(G4:G<>H4:H), TEXT(G4:G-H4:H, "[h]:mm:ss"), ))
```

[image: 0]